# Expressão regular de valor monetário

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Olá tenho a seguinte função

```
function CarregarMascaras() {
    $('[data-mascara=numeroMonetario]').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+[^\,]?[^0-9]+/g, '');
    }).on('paste', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+[^\,]?[^0-9]+/g, '');
    });
}
```

A ideia dela é a seguinte, enquanto você digita ela verifica o que tem lá e mantenha em uma formato tipo: **N**,**N**. Sendo que N uma quantidade números qualquer, mas ao testar ela está aceitando números do tipo **N**,**N**,**N** ou **N**.**N**.**N**. Gostaria que essa função aceitasse somente números do tipo: **N**,**N**.

Comment: Qual é a ideia ao usar o replace, é tirar todas as virgulas? a primeira caso multiplas ou a ultima caso multiplas?

Comment: a ideia é que seja aceito somente uma vírgula e qualquer quantidade de números antes e depois da vírgula, mas somente uma vírgula.

Comment: E neste caso `123456,4567893,46546132` qual das virgulas deveria ficar?

Comment: somente a primeira: Ex 123456,456789346546132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para remover as virgulas todas menos a primeira podes fazer assim:

```
$('[data-mascara="numeroMonetario"]').on('paste keyup', function() {
    this.value = this.value.split(/[^\d,]/).filter(Boolean).join('');
    var parts = this.value.split(',').filter(Boolean);
    if (parts.length > 1) this.value = [parts.shift()].concat(parts.join('')).join(',');
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/pet80e7o/1

**O que é que esse código faz?**

- junta ambos os eventos para não repetir o código
- com `this.value = this.value.split(/[^\d,]/).filter(Boolean).join('');` retiro tudo o que não seja numeros e virgulas
- com `var parts = this.value.split(',').filter(Boolean);;` parte o código em partes separadas por virgulas e limpa partes vazias
- `[parts.shift()]` guarda a primeira parte e retira-a de `parts`
- `parts.join('')` junta as outras partes sem virgulas
- `.join(',');` junta a primeira parte com o resto

Comment: é isso mesmo cara, obrigado mesmo =D